# touching others’ lives or touching other lives?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, phrases

Which of these is correct/more appropriate:

touching others’ lives

OR

touching other lives

Comment: They're both fine, just as wearing seat belts can *save lives* - not just yours, but also *other people's lives*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both grammatical and in use, meaning essentially the same thing. You touch other lives because you **are** a life, and you touch others' lives because you **have** a life.

Comment: ok so which one should I choose? I know both are grammatically correct. Does one have a better feel to it?

Comment: I feel indifferent to both, so how does one choose?